# Spring Security: <secutiry="none"> path is unavailable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I try to unsecure certain path with creating separate  for it:

```
<security:http pattern="/rest/**" security="none" />
```

but when I try to access URL matching this pattern, for example

```
my-host:8080/my-context-root/rest/users
```

**I receive 500 response with exception:**

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException:
>   An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

So that is the problem. Why I receive this? Why unsecured pattern, where all filters and security functionality should be completely disabled, waits for some credentials?

I'm not sure should I provide complete set of .xml conf files, but I can if it matters.

**UPDATE** my config

filter and servlet mapping:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring-db.xml
            classpath:spring-service.xml
            classpath:spring-service-security.xml
            classpath:spring-web-security.xml
            classpath:spring-web-dispatcher.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<!-- welcome file -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- session config -->
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

and security

```
spring-service-security.xml
    <security:global-method-security
        secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <bean id="authenticationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
        p:authenticationManager-ref="customAuthenticationManager" />

    <bean id="customAuthenticationManager" class="org.unidevteam.userstory.service.impl.AuthServiceImpl" />

    <bean id="passwordEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder" />

    <security:authentication-manager />
```

and spring-web-security.xml

```
<security:http pattern="/rest/**" security="none" />

    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        p:loginFormUrl="/login.html" />

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
        entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" access-denied-page="/login.html"
        authentication-manager-ref="customAuthenticationManager">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.html"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/home.html"
            access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ORGANIZER')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/users.html"
            access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ORGANIZER')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/rmuser.html"
            access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ORGANIZER')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/user.html"
            access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ORGANIZER')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/notifications.html"
            access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ORGANIZER')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/locations.html"
            access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ORGANIZER')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/rmlocation.html"
            access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ORGANIZER')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/location.html"
            access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ORGANIZER')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/events.html"
            access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ORGANIZER')" />
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
            logout-success-url="/logout.html" />
    </security:http>

    <bean id="authenticationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
        p:authenticationManager-ref="customAuthenticationManager" />
```

To clarify, what I'm trying to do...
There is a third-party old mvc application code, and now I need to implement rest api for it. So I decided that it will be available under /rest/ path. I'm planning to add some special security (probably token-based auth) for rest later, but initially I decided to unsecure that path completely for debug and testing purposes.

Comment: yes, please post your xml configuration file. May be that some path pattern overrides this one.

Comment: Can you post your `<filter-mapping />` and `<servlet-mapping />`?

Comment: can you post all your spring-security.xml file please ?

Comment: Updated question with configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never put security related config in servletdispatcher application container. Spring security is based on filters, and filters are declared at servlet context level, as is the root application context.

For that reason, I would advice you to put all spring security config in root application context - as all examples given in the reference manual do. The root application context is normally loaded by spring ContextLoaderListener that way :

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/daoContext.xml /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's brilliant advice! I just removed security-related stuff from dispatcher-related context-param section and the path /rest/* became unsecured. Anyway, I still don't understand fully  what's exactly happened, because before it I commented out <security:http security="none" ... /> tag. Sorry for my English.